# jQuery fireing all modal windows at once, even with different target #id

Tags: javascript, jquery, simplemodal

Its gonna be simple, I know!! but cant figure out why all my different Modal windows are being called at the same time, even though each nav link as a unique #id link attributed to it.

HTML - NAV

```
<div id="main" class="faded-in">
    <h3>
        <a class="js-modal" href="#about">ABOUT</a> &bull; 
        <a class="js-modal" href="#music">MUSIC</a> &bull; 
        <a class="js-modal" href="#live">LIVE</a> &bull;
    </h3>
</div><!-- end of #main -->
```

HTML - Modal window

```
<article id="about" class="modal faded-out">
    <div class="modal-spiel">
        <p>content</p>
    </div>
</article>

<article id="live" class="modal faded-out">
    <div class="modal-spiel">
        <p>content 2</p>
    </div><!-- end of .modal-spiel -->
</article><!-- end of .modal faded-out -->
```

css

(modal windows are used a full screen overlay, presenting different page content)

jQuery

```
}), $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tubular-mute").click(function() {
        $("a.tubular-mute").toggleClass("tubular-muted")
    }) 
})),$(".js-modal").click(function() {
    $("header, #main, .modal").toggleClass("faded-in").toggleClass("faded-out")
}), $(".modal").click(function() {
    $("header, #main, .modal").toggleClass("faded-in").toggleClass("faded-out")
});
```

Comment: What's up with your JS? It looks like the click handlers are being used as parameters in a function call. Can you post the full snippet please.

Comment: I have updated the JS snippet, I confess to hacking someone else's original build (usually tight deadline), were there is lots of other jQuery used for other actions. Think it was an initial framework build?

Comment: Are there only three `js-modal` elements or could it be dynamic `js-modal` elements?

Comment: @ekad only 3 js-modal elements - started with one, but i added a further two (each one act as a separate page overlay)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using this selector

```
$("header, #main, .modal").toggleClass("faded-in").toggleClass("faded-out")
```

You're telling jquery to execute `.toggleClass` method on all elements with `class="modal"`, and since there are more than one such elements, all of your modal windows are opened at the same time.

Assuming `ABOUT` link with `href="#about"` opens `#about` modal window, `MUSIC` link with `href="#music"` opens `#music` modal window, and `LIVE` link with `href="#live"` opens `#live` modal window, you can replace this part of code

```
$(".js-modal").click(function() {
    $("header, #main, .modal").toggleClass("faded-in").toggleClass("faded-out")
})
```

with this

```
$(".js-modal").click(function() {
    $($(this).attr("href")).toggleClass("faded-in").toggleClass("faded-out")
})
```

To close the modal on click, replace this

```
$(".modal").click(function() {
    $("header, #main, .modal").toggleClass("faded-in").toggleClass("faded-out")
});
```

with this

```
$(".modal").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("faded-in").toggleClass("faded-out")
});
```

Comment: Awesome, thats half of it solved, thanks loads @ekad it now opens the appropriate window but wont close on click. really need to learn more jQuery. thanks though.

Comment: See the updated answer, I guess that'd close the modal on click.

Comment: you @ekad are f**kin superstar!!!! very much appreciated. I just gained my saturday night back :-)